# Understanding Data.List's or & and w/ Empty Lists

Tags: haskell

[Hoogle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) explains Data.List's `or` and `and`:

> `and` returns the conjunction of a Boolean list. For the result to be
>   True, the list must be finite; False, however, results from a False
>   value at a finite index of a finite or infinite list.
>
> `or` returns the disjunction of a Boolean list. For the result to be
>   False, the list must be finite; True, however, results from a True
>   value at a finite index of a finite or infinite list.

Based on reading these definitions, why do `or []` and `and []` evaluate to `False` and `True`, respectively?

```
*Main> :m Data.List

Prelude Data.List> or []
False

Prelude Data.List> and []
True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and xs` corresponds to the statement "all elements of xs are true". The laws of mathematical logic say this should be equivalent to the statement "it is false that there exists an element in xs which is false" (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extensions) for some of the formal logic I'm alluding to).

It's obviously false that there exists an elements in the empty list which is false. So this suggests that `and []` should probably return True. Returning `False` would be inconsistent, though we could conceivably make it an error and just say that `and` is undefined on empty lists. But if someone has a use case where they would prefer *not* to get `True` from `and []`, then they can check explicitly for the empty list and do whatever they want to do instead; which is exactly what they'd have to do if `and []` threw a runtime error. So we don't really gain anything by making it error out, even for the use cases where `True` is an inappropriate answer, so we may as well maintain the analogy to logic and return `True`. And it's easier to implement that way, because you don't have to treat the empty list as a special case; the obvious fold just does the right thing: `and = foldr (&&) True`.

For `or` the same reasoning applies, just "the other way around". `or xs` corresponds to a statement "there exists an element of xs which is true". Seen that way, `or []` obviously doesn't contain any elements which are true, so the result should be `False`. And again, that both maintains the analogy to formal logic, and is the easiest thing to implement, so there's no reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

Operationally, `or` and `and` are folds with `(||)` and `(&&)` respectively. If we had `or [] = True` then `or` would always result `True`; analogously, `and [] = False` would mean `and` would always result `False`.

Semantically it also makes sense. I refer you to [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96080/in-satisfiability-what-is-the-difference-between-the-empty-clause-and-the-empty) for a nice explanation.

Comment: That makes clear sense to me. But, conceptually,  how could `or/and []` return True or False? There's nothing to evaluate

Comment: @KevinMeredith: They are being evaluated at the empty list, `[]`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith ...the empty list, which is the base case of `foldr`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/GHC-List.html#and), it's because they're defined as

```
and = foldr (&&) True
or  = foldr (||) False
```

So on empty lists `foldr` returns the initial value, `True` and `False` respectively for `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 2):

For `or`, `[]` is finite and it has no `True` values at any indices so it must be `False`. `[]` has no `False` values at any indices, so `and []` must be `True`.

This also works out nicely for the base cases of the recursion, since `False` is the identity for `or` and `True` is the identity for `and`. For all xs:

```
or  (False:xs) = or  xs
and (True :xs) = and xs
```

Those, incidentally, are part of the recursive definitions

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:

`or` returns `True` if any item in the list is `True` (otherwise `False`).

`or []`: How many `True` elements can you see there? None. So that's a `False` then.

`and` returns `False` if any item is `False`.

`and []`: Again, how many `False` elements can you see? None. So that's `True` then.